# Sending Huge Collection of DTOs back to Client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have prepared a DTO with 10 string properties. I need to pass a collection of 500 objects of these DTOs to client from WCF service.

```
//DTO with object info
[DataContract()]
public class RTVPIDObj
{
    public RTVPIDObj()
    {
    }
    [DataMember()]
    public string OBID { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string UID { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Whenever user requested, I need to pass properties of one selected object, which typically comprised of 500 string properties from WCF service.

```
//DTO with properties info
[DataContract()]
public class RTVPIDProp
{
    public RTVPIDProp()
    {
    }

    [DataMember()]
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I can pass this properties DTO when ever requested, but preparing that properties DTO at server side on the fly is taking long time.

So I am thinking to pass collection of object DTO where each object contains properties DTO also,  all at a time.

```
//DTO with object info and properties info
[DataContract()]
public class RTVPIDObj
{
    public RTVPIDObj()
    {
    }
    [DataMember()]
    public string OBID { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string UID { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    [DataMember()]
    public List<Tuple<string, string>> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

With the help of some background process, I can prepare this collection with properties also easily. Then, no need to do multiple client-server calls whenever object selected at client side.

Is this way of passing a huge size DTO (500 objects where each object comprised of 500 string collecion properties) to client is a bad approach? 
And is sending this kind of huge size DTO itself takes long time??? Any other way in achieving this?

Comment: Why would you want to give the client 500 objects with 500 properties each? Why does an object hold 500 properties?

Comment: Is this data going to change after the client receives it? Does the client care about that? If this is a one-time download of a bunch of static data, you could make it a compressed JSON or XML file.

Comment: Regarding 500 objects *500 properties, it's kind of business requirement. No, this data not going to change once client recieves. It's kind of report data. Yes, it is a one time download.